# Why does this rewrite to a Julia do block break when the lambda works?

Tags: lambda, types, julia, fold, dispatch

I have this lambda style function call

```
foldr((l,r) -> r+1, "12345"; init=0)
```

which Julia happily computes as 5. Rewriting it to the `do` style looks like

```
foldr("12345"; init=0) do (l,r)   # I also tried ((l,r),) and just tup
    # l,r = tup   # and then destructure here
    r+1
end
```

As far as I understood, these two should be equivalent. Unfortunately, Julia 1.7.0-rc3 doesn't agree with me:

> ERROR: MethodError: no method matching (::var"#36#37")(::Char, ::Int64)
> Closest candidates are:
> (::var"#36#37")(::Any) at REPL[25]:2
> Stacktrace:
> [1] FlipArgs
> @ ./reduce.jl:196 [inlined]
> [2] BottomRF
> @ ./reduce.jl:81 [inlined]
> [3] _foldl_impl(op::Base.BottomRF{Base.FlipArgs{var"#36#37"}}, init::Int64,   itr::Base.Iterators.Reverse{String})
> @ Base ./reduce.jl:58
> [4] foldl_impl(op::Base.BottomRF{Base.FlipArgs{var"#36#37"}}, nt::Int64,   itr::Base.Iterators.Reverse{String})
> @ Base ./reduce.jl:48
> [5] mapfoldr_impl(f::Function, op::Function, nt::Int64, itr::String)
> @ Base ./reduce.jl:186
> [6] #mapfoldr#246
> @ ./reduce.jl:205 [inlined]
> [7] #foldr#247
> @ ./reduce.jl:224 [inlined]
> [8] top-level scope
> @ REPL[25]:1

Why does the first form work but the second not? Can it be made to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses are not needed here:

```
julia> foldr("12345"; init=0) do l, r
           r+1
       end
5
```

if you write (l, r) after `do` it means you are passing one argument that has two elements that should be assigned to `l` and `r` respectively, e.g.:

```
julia> foreach([1:2, 3:4, 5:6]) do (x,y)
       @show x
       @show y
       end
x = 1
y = 2
x = 3
y = 4
x = 5
y = 6
```

See the [Julia Manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments) for an additional explanation of this rule.

Comment: This doesn't only happen with do blocks, either, you could define a function as `f( (x, y) ) = x+y`; it only takes 1 argument and tries to iterate it for 2 elements to assign to x and y. If you annotate its argument type for dispatch, you'll have to do this `f( (x, y)::UnitRange ) = x-y`. Multiple assignment like `x, y = someIterable` is called destructuring, and method argument destructuring is specifically documented in depth here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Argument-destructuring

Comment: Oh my, of course! I feel stupid. Wasn't there an older version of Julia where you needed to do it like this?

Comment: I have just checked the Julia 0.3 documentation and it uses `do a, b`, so it seems that it was always the recommended syntax (but indeed maybe in older Julia versions if you put parentheses around `a, b`  it worked since tuple destruction in method signatures was not supported then)